# NiFi - cannot download from registry flows containing nested versioned process groups

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I observed a strange behavior related to the nested versioned flows. I develop NiFi flows in two operating systems - Windows and Linux. I created process group with nested versioned process groups in Win-NiFi and pushed it into a NiFi Registry. When I'm trying to deploy this process groups from the same registry on Linux system I'm receiving the following error:

```
The Flow Registry with ID 5552e140-0169-1000-ffff-ffffc43e0ed7 reports that no Flow exists with Bucket a87ce054-7c96-48a6-a04d-55f7f3cfa8d2, Flow 42509fa3-1344-4e0b-aaee-1740e25cc366, Version 2
```

The similar situation occurs when I created the same flow with nested versioned process groups in Linux and tried to access it on Windows. Is this a known behavior or I am doing something wrong? NiFi Registry is running on Linux.

Comment: Have you tried to look into the File System of your NiFi Registry, if your nested groups are contained in the .snapshot file (the actual storage of your registry). If you are using git as the backend for NiFi Registry, you can manually check out the 'master' branch and navigate through your buckets to find the correct .snapshot file.